# Linearly compact module

Tags: reference-request

I must prove some results which relative to *linearly compact module*, but it is difficult to find all references. Two of them are :

1) T. Onodera,  Linearly compact modules and  cogenerators. J.  Fac.  Sci.  Hokkaido Univ.

2) F. L. Sandomierski, Linearly  compact  modules  and  local  Morita  duality:  Ring  theory, 333--346,  New  York  1972.

Can someone help me. Thank you.

Comment: You can check on this website https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linearly+compact+module